# runtime.exec() taking infinite time to execute code

Tags: java

I want to execute a command which takes 2 arguments.
1.input file name
2.output file name.

The command is sixV1.1 outputFile.txt
The code is:

```
   String cmd= "sixV1.1 <inputFile.txt >outputFile.txt";
   Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
   int retValue=p.waitFor();
```

when the i run above code,it is taking infinite time.
Is it possible to give <, > charecters in cmd .Please suggest me....

Comment: what is the size of the text file ?

Comment: *" ... it is taking infinite time"* - Are you sure?  Have you measured it?  :-)

Comment: the size of text file is around 2kb.The program is hangs after executing that line.I tried to print and tested it.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do input/output redirection when you start a process in Java is to write/read from the process's streams:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sixV1.1");
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
// read from is and write to outputFile.txt
OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
// read from inputFile.txt and write to os
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a fantastic [blog post](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=3) by Michael C. Daconta about successful command line calls using Runtime in Java. It's not as easy as you might think!

The following code extract from that blog post describes "MediocreExecJava", a class that successfully runs a program using Runtime.exec() and manages its input and output without hanging. I've used it before and it works. I highly recommend reading the post to understand why!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MediocreExecJavac
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {            
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec("javac");
            InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            System.out.println("<ERROR>");
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("</ERROR>");
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
        } catch (Throwable t)
          {
            t.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```